# Binding An Array Entry in an Image Source

Tags: html, angular

```
<img [src]=post.$value.split("|")[2]>
```

I want to bind the value `post.$value.split("|")[2]` to an image source. It is simply a string that comes from another string I have split. I want to avoid looping through another array since I have

```
*ngFor = 'let post of posts | async'
```

As the ngFor statement that loops over my elements and that is a FirebaseListObservable which I would like to avoid to mess with and keep like it is. For some reason html doesn't recognize the square brackets in the expression. What do I do, Angular won't recognize it using either the input [] syntax or the {{}}syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should surround your expression with quotes :

```
<img [src]="post.$value.split('|')[2]">
```